# tc filter parameter mtu significantly affects iperf bandwidth

Tags: linux, networking, traffic-shaping

I'm testing tc (traffic control) on a bond interface.

When setting the ingress filter to ratelimit 1Gbps with burst 100m and default mtu (2k), I actually get only less than 100Mbps bandwidth.

```
tc filter add dev bond3 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 0.0.0.0/0 police rate 1000mbit burst 100m drop flowid :1`
```

After changing the `mtu` parameter's value to 100k, I can finally reach 1Gbps.

```
tc filter add dev bond3 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 0.0.0.0/0 police rate 1000mbit burst 100m mtu 100k drop flowid :1
```

This is very confusing, can anybody explain it?